# Use Standard WebComponents in Angular Application

Tags: angular, typescript, web-component

I am trying to add two types of custom web components into an angular library. But from whatever reason apparently the web components do not work in angular application context they do not get loaded. If they are loaded outside of angular application context the web-components get loaded.

The examples are from typescript library generated with `ng g library`

Simple Web component

```
export class Foo extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
    
        this.innerHTML = 'foo';
      }
    }
    
    window.customElements.define('lib-foo', Foo);
```

Web component that extends HTMLButtonElement

```
 export class BarButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
      constructor() {
        super();
    
        this.innerHTML = 'BAR';
        this.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.reactToClick(e));
      }
    
      public reactToClick(e) {
        console.log('[REACTED TO CLICK]', e);
      }
    }
    
    window.customElements.define('lib-bar', BarButton, { extends: 'button'});
```

My app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My main.ts file

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import 'projects/components/src/public-api';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

My app.component.html

```
<button is='lib-bar'>Foo</button>
<lib-foo></lib-foo>
```

Comment: web components typically are loaded in an outside script tag. if you want to bundle the scripts, simply put them into the "scripts" array in angular.json.

Comment: If Custom Elements are created with ``document.createElement`` then there is no DOM when its ``constructor`` executes and it can't set ``.innerHTML``. You have to set HTML content in the ``connectedCallback``